# Promise inside NGRX effect

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, effects

I have been struggling to make this work. I am listening to `setTeam` action and checking if the image is null from the payload. If it's null, call the API and get blob and convert it to base64 and dispatch update action.

The code looks like this.

```
fetchImage = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(teamActions.setTeam),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectTeam))),
        switchMap(([payload]) => {
            if (!payload.team.teamLogoImage) {
                return this.teamService.getImage(payload.team.id)
                    .pipe(map((value => {
                        ImageUtils.getBase64(value); //returns promise
                        return teamActions.updateTeamLogoImage({teamLogoImage: val});
                    })))
            }
        })
    ));
```

The problem here is `ImageUtils.getBase64` returns Promise and I need to wait till this promise is resolved before dispatching updateTeamLogoImage action. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the Promise in RxJS [from](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from) function and handle `ImageUtils.getBase64` as Observable in pipe.

Comment: Can you please show me how?